# CSRF verfication failed. Request aborted error with Pinterest in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, csrf, pinterest

I am trying to integrate `Pinterest` in my iOS application.

Here is what I have tried.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_pinterestWebView.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [_pinterestWebView.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self postToPinterestWithImageUrl:_url andDescription:_description];

}
-(void)postToPinterestWithImageUrl:(NSString *)url andDescription:(NSString *)description
{

    NSString *buttonUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.flor.com&media=%@&description=%@", url, @"hello"];
    [_pinterestWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:buttonUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:40]];    
}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"WebView URL = %@",[request.URL absoluteString]);
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [_activityIndicator setHidden:NO];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {


    NSRange range = [[webView.request.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"login"];
    if (range.location==NSNotFound) {


        CGRect modifiedFrame = self.view.superview.frame;
        CGPoint center = self.view.superview.center;

        UIInterfaceOrientation orinetation= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orinetation)) {
            modifiedFrame.size=CGSizeMake(350, 650);
        }
        else
        {
            modifiedFrame.size=CGSizeMake(650, 350);
        }
        [self.view.superview setFrame:modifiedFrame];
        [self.view.superview setCenter:center];
        NSLog(@"Content Offset = %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(webView.scrollView.contentOffset));
        [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(40, 0)];

    }
    NSLog(@"Content Size = %@",NSStringFromCGSize([webView.scrollView contentSize]));
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [_activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error = %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setActivityIndicator:nil];
    [self setPinterestWebView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (IBAction)dismissIt:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

But, Once the webview is loaded with `pinterest` login page & if I change the orientation & try to login then I am getting the following message displayed on the webview.

[image]

What could be the problem?
Did I make any mistake in loading the `Pinterest` url? 
Also, always it is prompting for authentication. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is you are trying to make a request to Pinterest without the Django CSRF (Cross site request forgery) token.  You need to grab that CSRF token and put it into the request made in `postToPinterestWithImageUrl`.  Also, you are probably going to want to use a POST instead of a GET request when trying to interact with Pinterest in this way.  Also, the reason you are having to login every time is because you are using `NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed` as your cache policy, which ensures that nothing about the HTTP session, including session info, is saved to disk.  Try changing your cache policy to `NSURLCacheStorageAllowed`.

Comment: @sashimi.. I dint get you.. Even if I remove that cache policy removed also, I am getting the same error.

Also, How to make a post request? Could you give me an example for POST request in Pinterest? I am using a sample code from github. There also he is using the GET.

Comment: You should be loading HTML into a webview like he's doing in that project and include all the relevant javascript, etc.  Right now you're just doing a GET request directly to Pinterest that may need to be modified by the Pinterest JS.

Comment: But, I dont want to do it with that html button click action. If want to post when I click my iOS native button. Is there any other way post to Pinterest? Is there a `POST` request in pinterest?

Comment: Your best bet is to do things through a webview, as Pinterest does not have a public API.  See https://help.pinterest.com/entries/21151603-I-m-a-developer-Does-Pinterest-have-a-public-API-

Comment: No.. See this app. He is not doing it with webview. `itunes.com/apps/mazcontrol`

Comment: How do you know that this app isn't using a webview?

Comment: On just seeing itself you would understand. Have you checked this app/?